# (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final) mistake

Tags: python, file, buffer

I'm programming a function that reads the data in a file and prints it backwards, and prints the amount of characters in it. For this, I'm using

```
file=open("poem.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8");
x=file.read();
counter=len(x); #so here I could print counter to know the length of the file
```

Then I just print the variable x in the position of the counter and decrement counter.
This works fine for short files, with 2 to 5 lines, (as the name says, it must be a poem), but when I write the whole poem, it gives me this mistake

```
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 43: invalid continuation byte
```

I'm pretty sure it's because of the length of the file, like the variable x can't stand that much of data, I just wanted to make sure it was that.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't seem like a length problem at all. The error says it's a unicode error and tells you there's a byte that can't be decoded as utf-8. When you open the file you say the encoding is utf-8, but this error would indicate it isn't. You need to know the correct encoding.

Comment: Yeah, I found the mistake already, I didn't know the utf-8 couldn't decode those kind of characters (ñ, á, '), do you know which kind of encoding can?

Comment: utf-8 can decode these characters, but only if they were encoded in utf-8. You need to know the encoding of your input and it can be many different things (a lot of them can encode these characters and in incompatible ways). That said, when things aren't utf-8 (and are not ascii) they are often latin1

Comment: Utf-8 can handle the chacters just fine. However,  utf-8 is an **en**coding. That means, when you say `encoding="utf-8"` Python expects that this is the encoded format of the file. However, your file is encoded in another format. Perhaps `latin-1`? Thus, for Python to read it properly, you must tell that that is the encoding.

Comment: @Eran and JohanL, It worked fine with latin1, thank you, another question, how can I know the encoding of the input?

Comment: @LissethMartínez, This is a very difficult problem. Generally, encoding is not defined inherently in the data, and usually you need to know it in advance. There are libraries that try to figure it out ( for example libmagic) also if you can always try one and if that doesn't work try another as a fallback. But generally speaking when you are working with textual input you want to have this kind of knowledge in advance.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep this in mind next time, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the poem was in spanish, so characters like "ñ" or vowels with accent mark would generate this mistake. Also happens with apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was to change the file mode from read (r) to read byte(rb).

```py
def row_count1(filename, directory_name):

    path = os.path.join(directory_name,filename)

    num_rows = 0

    for row in open(path,"rb"):
        num_rows += 1

    return num_rows
```